# how to find and install PyVisa with AnacondaNavigator for python3.5 on W10-64b?

Tags: anaconda, navigator, pyvisa

The Anaconda Navigator documentation doesnt tell how to do it. Earlier i have used python2.7 where it was easy to install PyVisa1.4, but at the moment I am screwed with Anaconda. 
I installed Python3.5 together with Anaconda4.1-64bit, and the documentation says that the Navigator is used to find and install packages but I used several hours to find PyVisa1.8 and still dont know.

Comment: The following solves my PyVisa issue (it is amazing that somebody developed this nice AnacondaNavigator GUI just to make people waste their time with it! The only way to do it is obviously with a CMD terminal and the GUI is totally meaningless): In Anaconda Navigator> Environments, open root> Open Terminal> conda install pyvisa> didnt find anything. anaconda search -t conda pyvisa> finds 9 packages. anaconda show conda-forge/pyvisa> it suggests what to do. conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge pyvisa> now it installs PyVisa1.8 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue aswell. Finally i solved it with another work around.. I opend a terminal over the anaconda navigator in the environment where i want the package. Then i used pip. Just type in: pip install pyvisa

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `pyvisa` does not seem to be accessible from Anaconda Navigator. To install it you need to open your environment in the terminal:

[image: Open environment in terminal]

Then issue this command to install `pyvisa` from the official Conda-Forge Package Library:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyvisa
```